# Rpart model is achieving different results each run

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

I am using the same training and test set, but for some reason the confusion matrix and outputted plot are different each run. Each iteration achieves either of two accuracies:

```
fit_rpart <- train(goodbad~.,method='rpart',data=training, control = rpart.control(maxdepth = 30, minsplit=30, minbucket=1, cp=0.001))


fancyRpartPlot(fit_rpart$finalModel)

pred_rpart <- predict(fit_rpart, testing)
confusionMatrix(pred_rpart, testing$goodbad, positive = 'bad')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rpart` uses random sampling. Use `set.seed` before each run and you should get the same model each time.

```
set.seed(100)
fit_rpart <- train(goodbad~.,method='rpart',data=training, control = rpart.control(maxdepth = 30, minsplit=30, minbucket=1, cp=0.001))


fancyRpartPlot(fit_rpart$finalModel)

pred_rpart <- predict(fit_rpart, testing)
confusionMatrix(pred_rpart, testing$goodbad, positive = 'bad')
```